# seaborn scatterplot scale bubble size to larger dots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot

I am following this [example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) and I want to create larger bubbles but no matter how big I multiply the size column they are still tiny, is there some sort of scaling factor to adjust? I can't find it in the documentation.

```py
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)

cmap = sns.cubehelix_palette(dark=.3, light=.8, as_cmap=True)
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip",
                     hue="size", size="size",
                     palette=cmap,
                     data=tips)
```

[image]

```py
tips['size'] = 100 * tips['size']

ax = sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip",
                     hue="size", size="size",
                     palette=cmap,
                     data=tips)
```

[image]

Example code [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1IQIXmrUg0FduofEti-jJK5tAtSdE-iz7)

Comment: The documentation you link to has around 20 parameters to use for this. So you have a 1 in 20 chance of picking the right one.

Answer (score 9):

Apparently, you also need to use the `sizes` parameter in [`seaborn.scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) to achieve specified size range.

```
minsize = min(tips['size'])
maxsize = max(tips['size'])
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip",
                    hue="size", size="size", sizes=(minsize, maxsize),
                    palette=cmap,
                    data=tips)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thx for this method! it works great.
I had the same issue when setting big size fig with a lot of data. scatter appeared so tiny I couldn't distinguish the size.
so first set the tupple, the inject it into sns.scatter

btw, with this method you can play on minsize and maxsize with a multpiply factor without changing the actual data of size and thus the legend. I had to put minsize and maxsize to fifth power to make it readable! thank you so much!

```
minsize = min(df['value'])**5
maxsize = max(df['value'])**5
fx= sns.scatterplot(x=df['this'], y=df['that'], data=df, hue=df['takeway'], size=df['value'], sizes=(minsize, maxsize), legend='brief')
```